# InternetExplorer vs MSHTML2.XMLHTTP60 in VBA

Tags: html, vba, excel, automation, mshtml

I am having this irritable-IE syndrome while trying to control IE form VBA. I intend to open a website and look for a particular file (i.e. XLS) and then download it.

My Code:

```
Dim IE as InternetExplorer  ' I could also use "Object" here
Dim HTMLDoc as HTMLDocument
Dim OHTML_Element as IHTMLElement

Set IE = New InternetExplorer  ' I could also use "InternetExplorerMedium" here
IE.Silent = True
IE.Navigate (sURL)
IE.Visible = True

Set HTMLDoc = IE.document
mimtype = "Microsoft Office Excel 97-2003 Worksheet"
For Each oHTML_Element In HTMLDoc.Links
    If InStr(oHTML_Element.mimeType, mimtype) Then
        If InStr(oHTML_Element.href, FileType) Then
            ' Get the SOURCE file and DESTINATION files
            SRCfile = mainURL & oHTML_Element.pathname
            FileName = DESTPath & oHTML_Element.nameProp
            'Download the file
            ret = URLDownloadToFile(0, SRCfile, FileName, 0, 0)
            'See if the download happened correctly
            If ret = 0 Then
                'all went well
                GetFile = True
            Else
                MsgBox "There was a problem downloading the file.", vbCritical, "DOWNLOADING ERROR!"
                GetFile = False
                Exit Function
            End If
            Exit For
        End If
    End If
Next oHTML_Element
```

Now, this seemed to fairly work consistently for the past few months. From past two days, the system hangs after `IE.navigate(sURL`. In debugging mode, I can clearly see all the fields of the `IE` object that was created but after executing `IE.navigate(sURL)` all the fields of the object disappear however the website does open correctly. However, this problem is not very "consistent", so it might disappear or not hence its irritable! This "disappearing" fields is dangerous as further ahead i have a `if` condition to check if the fields are empty, if `True` to exit.

Just a bit of background, I am on Win 7, IE 11 (upgraded yesterday after this problem on IE 10, previously it was working with IE 10 for months)

After trawling the WWW, it appears some ppl are experiencing this problem. There was as a solution on Stackoverflow suggested to use `MSHTML.XMLHTTP60`. So, I tried,

```
Dim IE as MSHTML2.XMLHTTP60
Dim HTMLDoc as MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim HTMLBod as 

Set IE = new MSHTML2.XMLHTTP60
IE.open "Get", sURL, False
IE.send

Set HTMLDoc = new MSHTML.HTMLDocument
HTMLDoc.body.innerHtml  = IE.responseText

???? How do I proceed further to "search" for a XLS file and gets its "href" link?
```

I have tried looking at data (via Watch Window) inside `HTMLDoc` (using MSHTML) and `HTMLDoc` (using InternetExplorer) the data does not seem to be same. So my previous procedure of "search for mime-type & href and download" will not work.

I will really appreciate if someone can throw some light on it?. I am looking for a solution that will either help me rectify the inconsistent behaviour with `InternetExplorer` or a solution using `MSHTML2`

Comment: Is it possible that the website hasn't finished loading when you get to the `Set HTMLDoc = IE.document` line? It's usual to have a loop that checks the ready state of IE before trying to read the document. As a quick check, insert a 5 second pause before trying to read the document and see if that helps. Add this line immediately before the "Set HTMLDoc..." line in the 1st version of your code : `Application.Wait Now()+TimeValue("0:00:05")` If that works we can fine tune things from there

Comment: @barrowc Original version of the code had `Application.Wait Now() + TimeValue("0:00:05")`. However, my problem with `InternetExplorer` is not consistently reproducible, sometimes it fails immediately after `IE.navigate`,if it does not fail there, it continues without any glitch. Another interesting thing I noted was that whenever the glitch occurs the browser can been "seen" immediately after executing `IE.navigate` even before `IE.Visible=true`is executed! Which should not be occuring.

Comment: I am still struggling with it... with `dim IE as InternetExplorer`, after I execute `Set IE = New InternetExplorerMedium` the `IE` object gets instantiated but looking at the object window I can see that `IE.document` contains "Application Defined or object defined error". This error appears even before I `IE.navigate`. After I `IE.navigate` the browser opens with the webpage but I `IE` object has nothing inside it!!!

Comment: well, more updates...
Machine-1: Win 7 Home Premium, Excel 2007, IE 11 (ditto security settings) Same code when I execute `IE.navigate(url)`, IE opens in invisible mode (which is correct as I `IE.Visible=false`) and there are no glitches
Machine-2: Win 7 Professional, Excel 2007, IE 11 (ditto security settings) Same code when I execute `IE.navigate(url), IE opens in VISIBLE mode even though `IE.visible=false`, and I get all the problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well... after struggling with it for over 48 hours and trawling the web and finding nothing that would solve my `dim IE as InternetExplorer` type object problem, I have "finally" fingers-crossed have solved the `IE.Navigate(url)` crashing problem.

This error seems to happen because of some "wrong" setting within the IE browser, you might have changed the setting yourself or some add-on or some other actions might have changed these settings. The almightly "RESET" to the rescue! There is a "RESET" button within IE "Internet Options" dialog, this resets IE to standard settings and all the problems disappeared after I did this!!!